# pandas dtypes column coercion

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

What would cause pandas to set a column type to 'object' when the values I have checked are strings? I have explicitly set that column to `"string"` in the `dtypes` dictionary settings in the read_excel method call that loads in the data. I have checked for NaN or NULL etc, but haven't found any as I know that may cause an object type to be set. I recall reading string types need to set a max length but I was under the impression that pandas sets that to the max length of the column.

Edit 1:
this seems to only happen in fields holding email addresses. While I don't think this has an effect, would the @ character be triggering this behavior?

Comment: these email addresses - are they simple strings or hyperlinks in Excel? If so, does it make a difference if you remove the hyperlinks (copy + paste as plain text in Excel)?

Comment: If you do `df.convert_dtypes().dtypes` do you get the same result?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] if you hope for more help.  Surely pandas docs must say something about string storage.

Answer (score 0):

The dtype object comes from NumPy, it describes the type of element in a ndarray. Every element in an ndarray must have the same size in bytes. For int64 and float64, they are 8 bytes. But for strings, the length of the string is not fixed. So instead of saving the bytes of strings in the ndarray directly, Pandas uses an object ndarray, which saves pointers to objects; because of this the dtype of this kind ndarray is object.

Comment: yes, but as I mentioned above, doesn't pandas set that size to the columns max length, especially after I specifically set that column type to 'string' in the dtypes dict?

Comment: There's no such thing as a `string` dtype in `pandas`.  `numpy` does have fixed length string dtypes, e.g. 'U10', 'S20', but the pandas developers chose not to go that route.  Strings are plain python strings, which don't have a limit.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, yes there are. [pandas.StringDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.StringDtype.html#pandas.StringDtype) or [Text data types](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#text)

Comment: @BeRT2me any idea on what would cause an `object` type coersion when I've specified `string` as a type under dtypes?

Comment: @Verbal_Kint could be many different things, but it won't really be possible to diagnose your issue without a `minimal reproducible example` as mentioned above. Otherwise, all you're doing is making us guess, which isn't a very good way to ask a question~

Comment: @BeRT2me you're absolutely correct about reproducible examples, but I don't want any issue resolved really, just a better understanding as to what would cause an object coercion when a type has been specified under dtypes. Perhaps I should relabel the question...

Comment: 'string' is a pandas extension dtype, and concidered exprimental. I suspect it is still using python strings and object links, but with some added code to ensure consistency. I had no problems creating the dtype with `read_csv`